# Is it possible to create reports based on lists with SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create reports based on lists in SharePoint online. Is it possible? I don't want to use external tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is no great way to generate reports from sharepoint.  You can export your list to excel then create filters or sort the list depending on what you need to report off of.  You can also just create views for your list that will display data in a report like fashion.  Sharepoint is not really intended to be a reporting tool, it is mostly meant for a place for many users to view shared data and other resources.